# restrict swf file from playing on its own

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating a app for android using flash AS3. In my app, there are external swf files which are mostly games and slides. What I'm concerned about is, if you have apk file then you can extract swf files from it . So how can i restrict that swf file from playing if it is used without the main app. Is it possible without using another software ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. How do you define "external" swf files? On a network server? SD card? If a server and the URLs are publicly accessible then anything can get to them. If on SD card, the same applies although more recent versions of Android (I believe) provide certain private areas inaccessible by other apps. In saying that, however, if a device is rooted then any app can technically get access to any files anywhere.

Comment: External swf files are saved in a folder. When i compiled my app, I include those folders. I load those files from my app.

Comment: OK, I'll try again... *WHERE* is the folder? Internal storage, external storage, your app /assets or /raw folders???

Comment: folder are in same folder where the app is installed. Before I compile the app the folder is in same folder as the main file.

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying is impossible there is no trick for complete avoidance of reverse engineering.  if your user gets his hands on your apk file he can easily extract it and get the swf files you put there .

You can use a hack for naive users you can set your frame 2 to go back to frame 1 ie make a loop from frame 1-2-1-2... and start your actual file from frame 5 making it hard to see what's inside, And use it accordingly in your app.

use tools to encrypt or obfuscate  SWF files [see this](http://tekkie.flashbit.net/flash/as/protect-your-actionscript-code-with-swf-protector-)  though even this is not full-proof method.

Check everything in your swf that will allow it to run only on a particular OS ie sniff the OS it is running on if it is not the desired OS destroy stage and close . This can be done using flash.system.Capabilities class

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#version